# Adding Single Quotes Around A Scalar Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which I am trying to execute a @cmd variable which is a BACKUP database command. When I run the stored procedure (which is in a job through the reporting agent) I get an error with the 'C:' in my path, I believe because the path is not encased in quotes. How can I encase the @Filename variable I have to have quotes around it so the database backup command can work?

Here is the code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pAgentBackup
AS
--1. Declare Variables.
DECLARE @MaxID INT
DECLARE @MinID INT
DECLARE @CurrentID INT
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Type CHAR(1)
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Recovery VARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @Filename VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @CurrentID = 0, @MaxID = MAX(BKID) FROM DBBackups

--2. Loop through the columns in the table and execute the backups.
WHILE @CurrentID < @MaxID
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CurrentID = MIN(BKID) FROM DBBackups WHERE BKID > @CurrentID

        SELECT @DBName = DbName FROM DBBackups WHERE BKID = @CurrentID
        SELECT @Path = Path FROM DBBackups WHERE BKID = @CurrentID
        SELECT @Type = Type FROM DBBackups WHERE BKID = @CurrentID

        IF @Type = 'F'
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Recovery = CAST(DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'Recovery') AS VARCHAR(25))
                FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @DBName

                --Set recovery to full if it is not already turned on.
                IF @Recovery <> 'FULL'
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' SET RECOVERY FULL'
                        EXEC (@cmd)
                    END

                --BEGIN Backup
                SET @Filename = @Path + @DBName + 'Full' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '.bak'
                SET @cmd = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' TO DISK = ' + @Filename
                EXEC (@cmd)

                SET @Filename = @Path + '\Log' + @DBName + 'Log' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '.bak'
                SET @cmd = 'BACKUP LOG ' + @DBName + ' TO DISK = ' + @Filename
                EXEC (@cmd)
            END

        IF @Type = 'L'
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Recovery = CAST(DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'Recovery') AS VARCHAR(25))
                FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @DBName

                --Set recovery to full if it is not already turned on.
                IF @Recovery <> 'FULL'
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @cmd = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' SET RECOVERY FULL'
                        EXEC (@cmd)
                    END

                --Begin Backup
                SET @Filename = @Path + '\Log' + @DBName + 'Log' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '.bak'
                SET @cmd = 'BACKUP LOG ' + @DBName + ' TO DISK = ' + @Filename
                EXEC (@cmd)
            END
    END
GO
```

Comment: to test your theory, just add `set @filename = ''''+@filename+''''` somewhere in there that is appropriate.  and that will change something that was `file` to `'file'`.

Comment: concatinate with single qoutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query like

```
 SET @cmd = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @DBName + ' TO DISK = ''' + @Filename + ''''
```

Also change all queries where @Filename variable used in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
SET @cmd = 'BACKUP LOG ' + @DBName + ' TO DISK = ' + @Filename
```

with

```
SET @cmd = 'BACKUP LOG ' + @DBName + ' TO DISK = ' + ''''+ @Filename +''''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `REPLACE` + `QUOTENAME` makes the query much easier to read and maintain

```
SET @cmd = '
  BACKUP DATABASE @DBName 
  TO DISK = @Filename
';

SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '@DBName', QUOTENAME(@DBName));
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '@Filename', QUOTENAME(@Filename, ''''));
```